# Python executting twice while calling from php in server

Tags: php, python-2.7, cakephp, nginx, varnish

I have an  cakephp application that get the data from user and pass to python,which process the data and store the result in the folder which is created by cakephp application, But i am facing a problem that python is running twice while it is calling from php and finally php stops execution because multiple python execution. I am using nginx server,php5.5.9 and I am new to php,nginx

`Index.ctp(Ajax call to Controller)`

```
 $('#fileupload').on('change', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // $('#loader').show();
    var ext = $('#fileupload').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    var file = document.getElementById("fileupload").files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("fileupload", file);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'visualization/uploadandcreateInput',
            data: formdata,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            method: 'POST',
            xhr: function(){
              var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
              //Upload progress
              xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
              }, false);
              return xhr;
            },
            success: function(res){
              ret = JSON.parse(res);
              console.log(ret);
              if (ret.message == "Successfull"){
                window.inputfile = ret.filepath;
                window.outputdir = ret.outputpath;
                window.uniqueid_foreachupload = ret.uniqueid;
                // window.message = ret.message;

                alert("Successfully uploaded, Please click the Clean or Noise");
              }else if(ret.message == "do you want to continue"){
                confirmationfromuser = confirm("Data is inacurate, You want to continue?","myapp");  
                        // function(output){
                        if(confirmationfromuser==true){ 
                         window.inputfile = ret.filepath;
                         window.outputdir = ret.outputpath;
                         // window.message = ret.message;
                         alert("Please click Clean or Noise button");
                        }else {
                          alert("process is aborted.");
                           history.go(0);
                        }
                        // }
              }else{
                alert(ret.message);
                history.go(0);

              }

            }

        });

  });
  $('#clean').click(function(){
            $("#loader").show();
            window.button = "clean";
            if(window.cleanedoutputfilepath== undefined && window.inputfile!= undefined && window.outputdir!= undefined){
            $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'visualization/userconfirmedtocreate',
              data: {
                     input: window.inputfile,
                     outputpath: window.outputdir,
                     process: window.button,
                     uniqueid: window.uniqueid_foreachupload

              },
              dataType: 'Json',
              success: function(data){
                // console.log(data);
                     if(data.message == "Success!!!!!"){
                       window.cleanedoutputfilepath = data.filename;
                       if(typeof $('#renderer').html() != 'undefined'){
                          $('#renderer').remove();
                        }
                       call(data.filename);
                     }else{
                       alert(data.message);
                     }
              }

            });
          }else if (window.cleanedoutputfilepath != undefined && window.inputfile!= undefined && window.outputdir!= undefined){
                    if(typeof $('#renderer').html() != 'undefined'){
                          $('#renderer').remove();
                        }
                    call(window.cleanedoutputfilepath);
          }else if (window.inputfile== undefined && window.outputdir==undefined){
            alert("Please upload the data to process.");
          }
  });
```

`MyController.php`

```
  public function uploadandcreateInput(){
              $resp = array();

             $stringWithoutNonLetterCharacters = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s", "", $_FILES['fileupload']['name']);
              $filetoinsert = str_replace("%", "", $stringWithoutNonLetterCharacters);
              $filetoinsert = str_replace("!", "", $filetoinsert);
              $filetoinsert = str_replace("@", "", $filetoinsert);
              $filetoinsert = str_replace("#", "", $filetoinsert);
              $filetoinsert = str_replace("$", "", $filetoinsert);
              $filetoinsert = str_replace("^", "", $filetoinsert);
              $filetoinsert = str_replace("&", "", $filetoinsert);
              $filetoinsert = str_replace("*", "", $filetoinsert);
              $filetoinsert = str_replace("(", "", $filetoinsert);
              $filetoinsert = str_replace(")", "", $filetoinsert);
              $filetoinsert = str_replace("^", "", $filetoinsert);
              $filetoinsert = str_replace("<", "", $filetoinsert);
              $filetoinsert = str_replace(">", "", $filetoinsert);
              $filetoinsert = str_replace("/", "", $filetoinsert);
              $filetoinsert = str_replace("-", "", $filetoinsert);
              $filetoinsert = str_replace("_", "", $filetoinsert);
              $filetoinsert = str_replace("'", "", $filetoinsert);
              $filetoinsert = str_replace("\\", "", $filetoinsert);
              $filetoinsert = str_replace(",", "", $filetoinsert);
              $filetoinsert = str_replace("\"", "", $filetoinsert);

              $file = md5($_FILES['fileupload']['name']);
              $dir = "uploads/output/".$file;
              mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
              $ext=pathinfo($filetoinsert, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

              if($ext=='gz'){
                $filetoinsert = time().'_'.$filetoinsert;
                $filename = WWW_ROOT . $dir .'/'.$filetoinsert;
              }else{
                 $filetoinsert = time().'_'.$filetoinsert;
                 $filename = WWW_ROOT . $dir . DS . Inflector::slug(pathinfo($filetoinsert, PATHINFO_FILENAME)).'.'.pathinfo($filetoinsert, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
              }

              move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'], $filename);

              $outputpath=$dir.'/output/';

              $inputfilepath = $dir.'/output/NRRD/'; 
              mkdir($outputpath, 0777, true);

              $model = exec('python /var/www/myapp/app/webroot/mypython/myupload.py ' ."$filename".' '." $outputpath".' '.' 2>&1');


              if ($model == "Successfull"){
                $resp['filepath'] = $inputfilepath;// to send response
                $resp['outputpath'] = $outputpath;
                $resp['message'] = $model;
                $resp['uniqueid'] = "1";


              }else if($model == " do you want to continue"){
                 $resp['filepath'] = $inputfilepath;
                 $resp['outputpath'] = $outputpath;
                 $resp['message'] = $model;
                 $resp['uniqueid'] = "1";

              }else{
                 $resp['message'] = $model;

              }
              clearstatcache();
              echo json_encode($resp);
}
public function userconfirmedtocreate(){

             $this->autoRender = false;
             $this->layout='ajax';
             $inputfilepath=$_POST['input'];  
             $outputdirpath=$_POST['outputpath'];  
             $process=$_POST['process']; 


             $saltprintfile = '#p@$9f';

             $printfile = md5($outputdirpath.$saltprintfile.time());
             $viewfile = uniqid();

             $fullinputfilepath = '/var/www/myapp/app/webroot/'.$inputfilepath;
             $fulloutputdirpath = '/var/www/myapp/app/webroot/'.$outputdirpath;

             $model = exec('python /var/www/myapp/app/webroot/medical/test_node/create.py ' ."$fullinputfilepath". " $fulloutputdirpath ". " $viewfile ". " $printfile ". " $process " .' 2>&1');



              if ($model == "Success!!!!!" && $process == "clean"){
                $outputfilepathscan = scandir($outputdirpath.$viewfile,1);
                $threedmodelscan = scandir($outputdirpath.$printfile,1);


                $outputfilepath = $outputdirpath.$viewfile.'/'.$outputfilepathscan[0];
                $threedmodel = $outputdirpath.$printfile.'/'.$threedmodelscan[0];
                $resp['filename'] = $outputfilepath;// to send response
                $resp['message'] = $model;

              }else if ($model == "Success!!!!!" && $process == "original"){
                $outputfilepathscan = scandir($outputdirpath.$viewfile,1);
                // echo $outputfilepathscan;
                $threedmodelscan = scandir($outputdirpath.$printfile,1);
                $outputfilepath = $outputdirpath.$viewfile.'/'.$outputfilepathscan[0];
                $threedmodel = $outputdirpath.$printfile.'/'.$threedmodelscan[0];
                $resp['filename'] = $outputfilepath;// to send response
                $resp['message'] = $model;

              }else if ($model !== "Success!!!!!" && $process == "clean"){
                $resp['message'] = $model;
              }else if ($model !== "Success!!!!!" && $process == "original"){
                $resp['message'] = $model;
              }
              echo json_encode($resp);
}
```

Comment: You should show us the part of your code that calls the python application so we can see why it does that.

Comment: @Graou13 I have added the code can you please check